# Proving two claims about exact sequences and isomorphisms in abelian categories.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

In an proposition I'm reading the following claims are assumed but I'm not sure how these can be proved. In an abelian category  $\mathcal{C}$ lets have an exact sequence

$$
X_{1} \xrightarrow{f_1} X_{2} \xrightarrow{f_2}  X_{3} \xrightarrow{f_3} X_{4}  \xrightarrow{f_4} X_{5}
$$

where $f_{1}$ and $f_{4}$ are isomorphisms, then $X_{3}=0$. Also if we have an exact sequence

$$0 \xrightarrow{0} X_{1} \xrightarrow{f}  X_{2} \xrightarrow{0} 0$$

then $f$ is an isomorphism. For the second claim  my idea is to show $Ker(f)=0$ and $Im(f)=X_{2}$(not sure if this approach OK in an abelian category?) but by the fact we are in an exact sequence  and the left side of the sequence $Ker(f)=Im(0)=0$ and  by the right  side of the sequence $Im(f)=Ker(0)=X_{2}$. Appreciate your help!

Comment: How do you define an exact sequence in an abelian category? See for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/552080/on-the-definition-of-an-exact-sequence-in-an-abelian-category).

Comment: So my attempt to prove the second claim is OK? @DietrichBurde

Comment: We don't know. It depends on the definition of an exact sequence in an abelian category you are allowed to use. For example, call a sequence $0\rightarrow A\rightarrow B\rightarrow C$ left-exact in an abelian category if and only if the sequence of abelian groups $0\rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(C,T)\rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(B,T) \rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(A,T)$ is exact in $\mathcal{Ab}$ for all objects $T$, and a similar thing for right-exact. Then your attempt works.

Comment: Well, I'm using the first definition on the question you linked to me. This said Im not sure if my attempt for works :/  @DietrichBurde